# how to pass url id to different php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Now i have a face a problem which is i cant get the id for the page i have doing multiple room with different id which you can select what room you want. for example room a = id 1 and room b = id 2

[Here is picture let user select the room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNtb4.png)

once you select the url will be

- localhost/pme/main/chatRoom.php?chatroomID=1
- localhost/pme/main/chatRoom.php?chatroomID=2

i have a gui room page we call it as chatroom.php and multiple file for function but i have used

```
chatroomid = $_GET['chatroomID'];
```

this code i have place in all my function php file but when i insert to database the value is 0

- insertmessage.php - for insert message
- loadmessage.php - for load message

how can i pass the id to php function file?

this is my ajax file

```
    function submitChat(){
        var message = chatroom.message.value;
    if(chatroom.message.value == ''){
        alret('You didnt input any message');
        return;
    }

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var chatroomid = (location.search.match(/chatroomID=(\d+)/) || [])[0];  
    xmlhttp.open('GET','chatNew.php?&message='+ message +"&chatroomID="+chatroomid,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    $('.chatroom-message-container').scrollTop($('.chatroom-message-container').get(0).scrollHeight);
}

$(document).ready(function(e){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function(){$('#inner').load('chatMessage.php');}, 2000);

    $(".sendmessage-btn").click(function(){
        $("#area-message").val('');     
    });  
});

(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"chatRoom.php", 
            success:function(data)
            {
                setValue(data.value);
            },
            dataType:"json",
            complete:poll
        });
    },
    30000
            );  
});
```

Comment: The way I'd personally do this is `require_once()` the last file loaded in turn.. although that may not be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling these files via AJAX?

If so, you still need to add the parameters to those calls - remember even though they are being loaded in the same page as the original, as far as PHP is concerned they are completely independent requests.

So for example you'd have:

```
xhr.open("POST","insertmessage.php?chatroomID="+roomid,true);
```

You can get that room ID either by passing it in a data attribute, or by reading the query string in JS:

```
var roomid = (location.search.match(/chatroomID=(\d+)/) || [])[0];
if( !roomid) throw new Error("Could not find room ID.");
```

Comment: yes i have using ajax to call all the function file and i have edit my question with my ajax coding

Comment: Have you tried implementing the solution I have given you?

Comment: i no i use it on the correct way or no i cant receive the url id

Comment: i also try this but seem no work code = var chatroomid = (location.search.match(/chatroomID=(\d+)/) || [])[0]; 
        xmlhttp.open('GET','chatNew.php?&message='+ message +"&chatroomID="+chatroomid,true)

Comment: Does your `chatNew.php` file access `$_GET['chatroomID']` again? You can't just directly use `$chatroomid` because you haven't defined it in this new request.

Comment: ya my chatNew.php have used  **$chatroomID =$_GET['chatroomID'];**

Comment: you have to pass the $chatroomid variable  where you are calling the function.

Comment: @Gorakh how to do can you do a example for me? i am quite new with ajax

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank you～i was able to get the url id~~ sorry for the late reply